# One word noun for a person that is always seeking the truth?

Tags: single-word-requests

Could the word "dogmatic" be used as a noun meaning "a person that is always seeking the truth?" For example, is it valid to say that "Dogmatics had failed at truth seeking"? I am trying to understand the way that it is used in a translation of Friedrich Nietzsche's books. If we can't use "dogmatic" this way, what is a good alternative noun with this meaning?

Comment: truth in a psychological way.

Comment: A dogmatic person believes he has already found the truth. There's no seeking involved.

Comment: It is valid to say that "Dogmatics had failed at truth seeking?" Or not? I am trying to understand the way that Friedrich Nietzsche uses it.

Comment: Which noun would replace "Dogmatic" ? from the sentence from above?

Comment: Nietszche wrote in German.

Comment: The translation of his books, I refer to that I apologize.

Comment: There is no sentence in your question with the word **dogmatic** in it.

Comment: I edited your question to try to make it clearer and prevent people from closing it. The issue of what Nietzsche('s translator) meant by "dogmatics" is a separate question. But it does not mean "people who were seeking truth." You can find what it means in a dictionary, such as here: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dogmatics

Answer (score 5):

A person who is always seeking the truth is a truth seeker. Dogmatism is usually someone who believes she has found the truth and refuses to even listen to other viewpoints. And not just about the truth either.

Answer (score 2):

Veracity - habitual observance of truth in speech or statement; truthfulness:: [Source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/veracity)

Comment: It is possible to use "veracity" to describe people?

Comment: The trial began with a flurry of motions and questions challenging the judge's authority and veracity. The defendants earlier had called the judge's authority into question when jurors were selected two weeks ago. —Chris Bird, San Antonio Express-News, 23 Jan. 1996
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
He was so veracious a man, that it was said of him, after his death, “Truth died with Matyas.”

The Romany Rye 
George Borrow

Comment: That would be a truth speaker, wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe this is too meta-philosophy for ELU, though it seems to me one cannot speak the truth, unless one knows the truth. So to be a truth speaker, would to me imply, one has accumulated enough truth to be able to recite it.

Answer (score 1):

**Philosopher** may fit.

Opposite to a "dogmatic" person who thinks that he holds the truth, philosophy is the tireless passion in the search of truth, that extends little by little to all human activities and desires.

Comment: I didn't tough about that, thanks nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Would he not  be simply a philosopher?
C.G.Jung  is by far the greatest. Among many others thinkings :

“The pendulum of the mind oscillates between sense and nonsense, not between right and wrong.” 
“To find out what is truly individual in ourselves, profound reflection is needed; 
and suddenly we realize how uncommonly difficult the discovery of individuality is.”

Answer (score 0):

This person is "determined" or "focus"ed, perhaps sure of themselves, although that spans three words. They may even be "obsessed".

Sadly (tragically?) English, my only language, needs work, and a single word may be illusive without further context.

Is this a spiritual truth, a scientific truth, a search for the honesty of others, perhaps even for justice, or a "soul search" for the internal honesty of oneself?

In the fictional series DiscWorld, William De Word considers himself to be beholden to the truth in his reporting, Captain Carrot also has a great deal of trouble with deceit or lies, despite his position of power. It's an astonishingly believably rich, deep and real, fantastical fantasy world, where a drive for vertues such as truth, law and morals come up, recur, again and again.